# Function to Produce Repeating Spikes

Tags: r, function, signals

I asked a similar question on CrossValidated, but did not get a response.  I went ahead anyway, and built out a function but am having a problem with replication...

The [original question, posted here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360476/function-to-produce-periodic-spike-and-decay)  is as such:

> I am seeking a function (or short algorithm, ideally implemented in R) that produces something similar to the following:
>
> [image: spikes]
>
> See, I would like to be able to generate a vector of n items that follows this sort of pattern, mapped to a set of inputs (say, seq(1:n)). Ideally, I would be able to tell the algorithm to "spike" to a maximum height h on every kth time period, and decay at rate r. However, I would be sufficiently happy with simply being able to generate a spike pattern that occurs periodically.

I wrote some code in R, which is included here, that works fairly well...

```
## Neural Networks / Deep Learning ##
# first, must install Python from:
#    https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows
#    https://www.python.org/downloads/
if (!require(keras)) devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras") ; library(keras)
# install_tensorflow()

spikes_model <- function(maxiter, total_spikes = 10, max_height = 0.001, min_height = 0.000005, decay_rate = 1) {
  value_at_iteration <- rep(0, maxiter)
  spike_at <- maxiter / total_spikes
  current_rate <- min_height
  holder_timeval <- 0
  for(i in 1:maxiter) {
    spike_indicator <- i / spike_at
    if (is.integer(spike_indicator)) {
      current_rate <- max_height
      value_at_iteration[i] <- current_rate
      holder_timeval <- spike_indicator
    } else if (i < spike_at) {
      current_rate <- min_height
      value_at_iteration[i] <- current_rate
    } else {
      timeval <- i - (holder_timeval*spike_at)
      current_rate <- max_height*exp(-decay_rate*timeval) + min_height
      value_at_iteration[i] <- current_rate
    }
  }
  return(value_at_iteration)
}

asdf <- spikes_model(maxiter = 100)
plot(asdf, type="l")
```

... which results in the following plot:

[image: result plot]

This is exactly what I want, except there is only one spike.  I know there is a code or logic error somewhere, but I can not find where I am going wrong.  Please help me replicate this spike procedure across time.

The code this scheduler is used in:

```
eps <- 1000
sch <- spikes_model(eps)
lr_schedule <- function(epoch, lr) {
  lrn <- sch[as.integer(epoch)]
  lrn <- k_cast_to_floatx(lrn)
  return(lrn)
}
## Add callback to automatically adjust learning rate downward when training reaches plateau ##
reduce_lr <- callback_learning_rate_scheduler(lr_schedule)

## Fit model using trainig data, validate with validation data ##
mod1.hst <- mod1 %>% fit(
  x=X.train, y=Y.train,
  epochs=eps, batch_size=nrow(X.train),
  validation_data = list(X.val, Y.val),
  shuffle=TRUE, callbacks = list(checkpoint, reduce_lr)
)
```

Comment: Good MCVE (+1), but question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut This function is used to introduce intermittent spikes in the learning rate of a `keras`-based neural network in R.  It absolutely has to do with machine learning, and I assume people in the future will use this question for that exact reason.  Look for the image labeled *"Comparing fixed LR and Cyclic LR"* in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-learning-rates-and-how-it-improves-performance-in-deep-learning-d0d4059c1c10).

Comment: The fact that I may need a generic function which I will use downstream for an apparatus on a spaceship does not automatically make the question related to `space-engineering`... And there are much more straightforward methods to produce cyclical LR's.

Comment: That is fair.  However, the function here is used directly in a machine learning process, and is built for a machine learning process.  I felt it warranted the tags.  You can remove them if you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I just figured out my own error.  I was using the `is.integer()` function, which does not work how I wanted.  I needed to use the `is.whole.number()` function from `mosaic`.

Fixing that single error, I find the following chart, which is ***exactly*** what I wanted.

[image: beauty]

Comment: It would be interesting to include the whole code (or at least the specific parts affected), including possible necessary imports (what is `mosaic`?).

Comment: Will add momentarily